# how to make a database timestamp relevant to user timezone

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried searching, but do not seem to be clearly getting an answer for my question, but it seems so simple it maybe my newbie skills are still too green to understand, so please go easy.

I have created a sports prediction comp on my website using a MySQL DB & PHP connection.

All works, but one issue I have is that my website has members from all over the world.  How do I get the time of the game, and the cut off time for submitting predictions, to show in their own timezone?  All matches in the DB are set to the local time for the match itself (which is GMT in this case, but isn't always the case).

Appreciate the assistance of you experts to help me improve my skills.  Sorry if it's a common question, happy to be pointed towards a relevant link.

Thank you again.

RB

Answer (score 0):

The most common method is to use a UTC timestamp, then when displaying the time, adjust it to the locale of the user.  This requires that a local for each user has been provided.  If it has not, note the UTC on the timestamp when shown to them.

The UTC method ensures that you can accurately determine the TRUE sequence of insert/update events, using the table data, vs having to examine txn logs.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The duplicate losted gives a good example of what I was looking for. Apologies for the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can let your users specify their location (time zone) within their preferences and your DB uses its own, then do the math